# CSS @font-face is not loading the font file. But the file path is correct (I can fetch it)

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, font-face

I've got some CSS with an `@font-face` in it:

```html
<style>
@font-face {
  src: url('file:///Users/trusktr/src/my-project/node_modules/my-lib/dist/assets/fonts/AvenirNext/AvenirNext-DemiBold.woff') format('woff');
  src: url('file:///Users/trusktr/src/my-project/node_modules/my-lib/dist/assets/fonts/AvenirNext/AvenirNext-DemiBold.svg') format('svg');
  src: url('file:///Users/trusktr/src/my-project/node_modules/my-lib/dist/assets/fonts/AvenirNext/AvenirNext-DemiBold.truetype') format('truetype');
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  src: url('file:///Users/trusktr/src/my-project/node_modules/my-lib/dist/assets/fonts/AvenirNext/AvenirNext-DemiBold.eot');
  font-style: normal;
}
* {
  background: red;
}
.App-root-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

When I check the network tab, I don't see any request for those font file.

However, if I create a `fetch()` call using one of them, I do see output in the console:

```js
fetch('file:///Users/trusktr/src/my-project/node_modules/my-lib/dist/assets/fonts/AvenirNext/AvenirNext-DemiBold.svg').then(r => r.text()).then(console.log)
```

and I see something like

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?> <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd" > <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
<defs >
<font id="AvenirNext-Heavy" ...>
...
```

So I'm wondering, if I don't see the request for the font file in the Network tab, does that mean it didn't load? And if it didn't load, why not? Did I do something wrong in the `@font-face` rule?

Comment: Are you viewing the HTML file truly locally (from a `file://` URL) or via a local server (from `https://localhost:port` or the like)?

Comment: @Draconis all locally, from `file://`. I'm running in Electron, and there's no server running.

Comment: Can you try relative path ?!

Comment: @Conan Figured it out, posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by putting the `url()`s into a single `src` property:

```css
@font-face {
  src: url('file:///Users/trusktr/src/my-project/node_modules/my-lib/dist/assets/fonts/AvenirNext/AvenirNext-DemiBold.eot'),
    url('file:///Users/trusktr/src/my-project/node_modules/my-lib/dist/assets/fonts/AvenirNext/AvenirNext-DemiBold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('file:///Users/trusktr/src/my-project/node_modules/my-lib/dist/assets/fonts/AvenirNext/AvenirNext-DemiBold.svg') format('svg'),
    url('file:///Users/trusktr/src/my-project/node_modules/my-lib/dist/assets/fonts/AvenirNext/AvenirNext-DemiBold.truetype') format('truetype');
  font-family: AvenirNext;
  font-style: normal;
}
```